# No space left on device - Size=105G, Used=55G, Avail=0

Tags: filesystem, btrfs, df

My root filesystem claims I have no space left on device. I've done some searching and can't find anyone with the problem I'm having.

If you look at `/` you can see that the partition is `105G`, used is `55G`, yet avail is `0`.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           379M  5.7M  373M   2% /run
/dev/sdf2       105G   55G     0 100% /
```

`df -hi` gives this:

```
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev             469K   492  468K    1% /dev
tmpfs            473K   699  473K    1% /run
/dev/sdf2           0     0     0     - /
```

I'm not sure what my problem is or how to fix it.
Filesystem is btrfs

Edit:

`sudo lsof | grep -i deleted`

```
php-fpm7. 3062                  root    3u      REG               0,22        0    2909438 /tmp/.ZendSem.sB49NQ (deleted)
php-fpm7. 3086              www-data    3u      REG               0,22        0    2909438 /tmp/.ZendSem.sB49NQ (deleted)
php-fpm7. 3087              www-data    3u      REG               0,22        0    2909438 /tmp/.ZendSem.sB49NQ (deleted)
```

Edit 2:

`sudo btrfs fi df /`

```
Data, single: total=102.14GiB, used=52.38GiB
System, single: total=4.00MiB, used=16.00KiB
Metadata, single: total=2.01GiB, used=1.50GiB
GlobalReserve, single: total=512.00MiB, used=0.00B
```

Comment: See also reply http://askubuntu.com/a/903178/475088 to my question, saying that Size - Used != Avail.

Comment: Are you saying I've lost 50G of space (about 47% of my total space) to reserved blocks?

Comment: Is it the same output if you run your first `df -h` command with and without `sudo`?

Comment: Can confirm. They are the same.

Comment: btrfs is able to do snapshots, what means deleting files does not free disk space (as the space still is occupied by the snapshot).

Comment: I was actually attempting to restore a snapshot after a bad upgrade. I'm at the point where I am trying to mv @_snapshot/ to @/, and this error I'm hoping is unrelated.

Comment: You can't "move" snapshots, as they are readonly. You only can "delete" snapshots, which might free disk space. I don't use btrfs, so I cannot give more advice.

Comment: `df` is not reliable with btrfs, which has its own version

Comment: fsck /dev/sdf2 ?