# Ubuntu guest freezes on logo after VirtualBox compacting VDI

Tags: boot, 20.04, virtualbox

Ubuntu 20.04 (or higher, not sure) guest in VirtualBox 6.1.16 on Windows 10 Pro host

As I had a lot of deleted files (I think around 200GB), I did run the commands in https://askubuntu.com/a/997409/962974

Guest Ubuntu:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/home/zero bs=1M
shutdown
```

Host Win7 in cmd:

```
C:/virtualbox/vboxmanage.exe modifymedium --compact MyPathTo/MyVM.vdi
```

After booting the guest, I no see a black screen with Ubuntu logo. The logfiles aren't changed for some time and I don't see any errors in the last rows of the files.

The space on the harddisk is free again. Sending a shutdown signal through VirtualBox doesn't trigger a shutdown.

How can I fix the guest so it will boot again?

Answer (score 0):

The VDI disk was full (visible after mounting this VDI in another guest).
Increasing the disk size fixed booting.